# Maven build 3x as slow on OSX

Tags: performance, maven-2, osx-lion

I recently got a new Macbook Pro at work and noticed that building our codebase in Maven2 takes about 15 minutes while others on my team with slightly older Macbooks (but similar/same specs) build in about 5 minutes. After asking around, I've found one other person on my team whose builds take 15+ minutes. I'm talking about a fresh checkout of the code, with all of us on the same version of Maven (2.2.1) and Java version: 1.6.0_29, running 'mvn clean install' from the root of the project. Both of us with slow builds are on Lion (10.7.3), while the people with 5 minute builds are on Lion or Snow Leopard. My machine has 8GB RAM with 2.3 GHz i7, so it doesn't seem like that should be a problem. AFAIK, the machine came with Lion (versus upgraded from Snow Leopard) so I don't think it's that it was upgraded in place from Snow Leopard which it seems some people have had issues with. We with the slow builds both have 5400 RPM drives while most of the others have 7200 RPM drives, but alas, one of the other guys with the 5 minute builds has the exact same 5400 RPM drive as us ... so that sort of rules out that theory.

I've run a memory test (checked out fine), run disk verify and permissions repair in Disk Utility (fixed some permission issues, but didn't change build times), disabled swapping, made sure filevault was off, build from a different directory, all to no avail. A few interesting points which makes me suspect an OS issue:

1. I have a Ubuntu VM on said machine, and doing a 'mvn clean install' in there is even considerably faster than natively in OSX (10 minutes versus 15 minutes)! FYI, the native Ubuntu guys on our team also build around 5 minutes. And when I was running Ubuntu in a VM on my Windows box a few months ago, builds averaged 15-20 minutes.
2. Building the slowest component of our project by itself takes about 3-4 minutes normally. The interesting thing about this component is that there is very little code in it. In fact, all it is is one test case and 135 MB of resource files. Of the 3-4 minutes, I counted about 100+ seconds of it is sitting on "Copying 63 resources".
3. Running in OSX Safe Mode, building the aforementioned slowest component took only 42 seconds, of which about 7 seconds were spent on copying the 63 resources.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point, but I feel I'm so close to nailing it down. If it wasn't such a marked difference, I wouldn't worry about it so much, but 15 mins versus 5 mins is huge in my workflow. I don't feel real comfortable about giving my work computer to the Apple Genius guys, and our IT guy's not a Mac person. Reinstalling the OS seems to be the answer I've seen online, but that seems a bit excessive and intrusive. (I realize this is more of an OSX question than a Maven question, probably, but Maven's been my benchmark. I don't notice any other slowness, but it's hard to say without using others' computers)

Has anyone encountered something like this? Any ideas on what to try? Thanks

Comment: In my workplace my builds are slower on my OSX machine than my personal lower specced machine, that's because my workplace has IMHO incorrectly joined the machine to an AD domain and installed antivirus, I don't know the specific cause but both have identical software. Apart from that my personal machine builds faster than a much higher specced RHEL 5.11 that has twice the ram and double the cores.

Answer (score 2):

Run `mvn -X ...` command on your machine and on fast one and compare times from the log files what tasks/plugins take the most time. That should give you a starting point. The two slowest parts are file system scanning and network access for checking artifacts/dependencies/plugin updates.

The former can be improved by tuning disk access (e.g. cache or switching to the SSD).

The latter can be improved by adding Maven repository manager, such as Nexus or Artifactory that would cache and optimize access to all remote Maven repositories.

Comment: +1 for artifactory tip. I saw significant speed up after installing artifactory locally.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Have been busy with other things to worry about this. Thanks for the ideas. We already use Artifactory, and the mvn -X comparison didn't reveal anything obvious. I haven't abandoned this question though, so please don't close don't archive it just yet. The other teammate with the similar issue ended up reinstalling OSX to resolve the issue which I always figured would work. I may end up doing this eventually, but it'll still bug me as to what was wrong. He said that reinstall of Lion didn't help, but had to downgrade to Snow Leopard.